# Image is not Retrieving from SQlite Database

Tags: java, android

I have stored images in database now i want to retrieve it and display it on a listview in my app but i am not able to do so, i am not getting the image length in byte, any suggessions what should i do,
here is my retrieving code,

**User Class**

```
public class User {
String FirstName, LastName, Email;
byte[] Image;

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, byte[] image) {
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    Email = email;
    Image = image;

}
public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    FirstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    LastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}

public byte[] getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {

    Image = image;
}}
```

**User Adapter**

```
public class UserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<User> arrayList;

public UserAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<User> arrayList){
    this.context=context;
    this.arrayList=arrayList;
}
public  class  Holder{
    TextView textView1,textView2,textView3;
    ImageView imageView;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder viewHolder;


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_listview, null);
   /* TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Firstname);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Lastname);
    TextView textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userProfile);
    user user= arrayList.get(position);
    textView1.setText(user.getFirstName());
    textView2.setText(user.getLastName());
    textView3.setText(user.getEmail());*/
        viewHolder = new Holder();
        viewHolder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Firstname);
        viewHolder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Lastname);
        viewHolder.textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userProfile);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    User user = arrayList.get(position);
        viewHolder.textView1.setText(user.getFirstName());
        viewHolder.textView2.setText(user.getLastName());
        viewHolder.textView3.setText(user.getEmail());


    byte[] image = user.getImage();
    Log.e("Image Length", "" + image.length);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return convertView;

    }}
```

**DBHandler**

```
    public ArrayList<User> getAllData(){

    ArrayList<User> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Bitmap bt = null;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM formValidation" ,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String FirstName = cursor.getString(0);
            String LastName = cursor.getString(1);
            String Email = cursor.getString(2);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);
            Log.e("Image Length here", "" + image.length);
            User user = new User(FirstName, LastName, Email, image);
            arrayList.add(user);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return arrayList;
}}
```

The length printed in logcat is showing this

```
2021-12-14 20:12:21.907 15459-15459/com.example.myapplication E/Image Length here: 9
```

Comment: For a start I would change `SELECT * FROM formValidation` to specifically state the columns by name

Comment: anyone plz help me out

Comment: so did you do my suggestion?

Comment: yup but nothing changed same issue , i am not getting any error then where is the problem i don't know